# Query to list data that's not listed in another column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

```
=QUERY({startingdates!D2:D, Cancelledtours!D2:D},"Select Col1 where not(Col1) matches Col2")
```

This seems to work for Column A but not column D. I'm at a dead-end. Can anyone help?

Sheet- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEQmNs48CsaaioQOcwuK97kcmnDLDfX-57nuXFaLujc/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The reason that you are having problems with Column D is... it is the only one with any Cancelled Dates.

Comment: your formula is just wrong and it works for A column just by coincidence

Comment: I added the first tour date in col A and it worked, maybe I was mistaken though. Not at the computer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a lookup on the starting date - the query as it stands only looks in the same row to see if there is a match:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({StartingDates!D2:D, isnumber(vlookup(StartingDates!D2:D,CancelledTours!D2:D,1,false))},"Select Col1 where Col2=false"))
```

or slightly shorter using match:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({StartingDates!D2:D, isnumber(match(StartingDates!D2:D,CancelledTours!D2:D,0))},"Select Col1 where Col2=false"))
```

[image]

Reversing the logic, this also works:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({StartingDates!D2:D, isna(match(StartingDates!D2:D,CancelledTours!D2:D,0))},"Select Col1 where Col2=true"))
```

Comment: Interesting, though irrelevant, that this bypasses the [date literal](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals) "rule" in QUERY

Comment: Good point, I didn't really think about that, but I wasn't sure until I tried it (confirmed by your reference) that literals true and false are allowed. I wondered if you could put 'where not Col2' - no you can't, 'not' only works with a boolean expression so you would have to say 'where not Col2=true':-)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(startingdates!D2:D, NOT(COUNTIF(Cancelledtours!D2:D, startingdates!D2:D)))
```

[image: 0]